# Create an SQL where conditions and name it

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and have a question, I'm not sure if this is possible or not if not please let me know.

I want to create multiple where queries in an SQL query and then name this so it can be counted.

For example I have multiple different possibilites for certain fields;

So the names would be Data_over_5mins and Data_61_300sec

```
(WHERE service_request_type = 'a' AND l_service_req_trigger = 'b' AND paging_attempts_enb = '0' AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '0' AND paging_attempts_ta = '0' AND paging_attempts_ta_list = '4') Data_over_5mins
```

and

```
(WHERE service_request_type = 'c' AND l_service_req_trigger = 'd' AND paging_attempts_enb = '0' AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '1' AND paging_attempts_ta = '2' AND paging_attempts_ta_list = '0') Data_61_300sec
```

There are about a number of different options to this.

So I want to (possibly not the correct term) nest these where queries so they can all be run in the same single query and counted.

Sorry I might be using totally the wrong terminalogy but as I say I'm new to this and can't find the answer on the internet.

I've tried variations on the below with no luck

```
SELECT dt,lkey,node,sgw,cause_code,sub_cause_code,Data_0_60sec,Data_61_300sec,Data_over_5mins,count(*) 
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM table_1
   WHERE date = y
   (WHERE service_request_type = 'a' AND l_service_req_trigger = 'b' AND paging_attempts_enb = '0' AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '0' AND paging_attempts_ta = '0' AND paging_attempts_ta_list = '4') Data_over_5mins
   (WHERE service_request_type = 'c' AND l_service_req_trigger = 'd' AND paging_attempts_enb = '0' AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '1' AND paging_attempts_ta = '2' AND paging_attempts_ta_list = '0') Data_61_300sec
GROUP BY dt,lkey,node,sgw,cause_code,sub_cause_code,Data_0_60sec_Profile_4,Data_61_300sec_Profile_5,Data_over_5mins_Profile_1
```

Comment: Instead of a WHERE condition, you want a CASE expression (or iif() function, depending on your RDBMS) in your SELECT clause. Can you share what RDBMS you are using so we can guide better (sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, ms access, etc).

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    dt, lkey, node, sgw, cause_code, sub_cause_code,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN service_request_type = 'a'
            AND l_service_req_trigger = 'b'
            AND paging_attempts_enb = '0'
            AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '0'
            AND paging_attempts_ta = '0'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS Data_0_60sec,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN service_request_type = 'c'
            AND l_service_req_trigger = 'd'
            AND paging_attempts_enb = '0'
            AND paging_attempts_enb_list = '1'
            AND paging_attempts_ta = '2'
            AND paging_attempts_ta_list = '0'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS Data_61_300sec,
    count(*) as c
FROM
    table_1
GROUP BY
    dt, lkey, node, sgw, cause_code, sub_cause_code
```